# RowDefinition GridUnitType.Star is ignored

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I have the following code where I put a ScrollViewer in row 1 and buttons and text in the other rows. The first row (row 0) displays properly but the ScrollViewer takes the rest of the screen. The buttons in the following rows are pushed off the screen and are not visible. If I hardcode the height for the ScrollViewer it works OK, but I don't want to do this. It seems that my GridUnitType.Star command is being ignored. What am I missing?

```
Grid mainGrid = new Grid();
mainGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
mainGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
    if (i == 1) // scrollview = 1
    {
        r.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star); // take 100% of the remaining height
        //r = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(300) };
    }
    else
    {
        r.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto); // wrap the height
    }
    mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: try to set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` in the ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 0):

it works as expected today. I guess quitting and restarting visual studio must have reset something.